# How to unit test class that reference concrete factory class in ASP.NET MVC Controller or Main()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, factory

I am learning to write unit test for mvc controller. However, in one of my controller, it references on concrete factory instance, let's call it 'ConcreteFactory', however, in this case, I have no ideas how to test this controller, because I really do not want to have the factory class instance return a real/production instance and I suppose this should not be for a good unit test, is there some way to refactor my codes and mock the instance the facotry class returns?

FACTORY:

```
Public Abstract class BaseFactory
{
    public ICalculator GetCalculator();
}

public class ConcreteFactory
{
    public ICalculator GetCalculator();
    {
        return new MyCalculator();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET CONTROLLER:

```
Public ViewResult GetResult()
{
    var result=(new ConcreteFactory()).GetCalculator();
    return View(result);
}
```

Much Appreciated.

Comment: you will need to use dependency injection to provide a concrete implementation of `BaseFactory` to your controller, instead of directly instantiating it (`new ConcreteFactory()`). This will enable you to provide a fake implementation of `BaseFactory` to the controller in your tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can test it but you wont be ably to skip the code

```
var result=(new ConcreteFactory()).GetCalculator();
```

To do this, you will have to use Dependency Injection implementation for IoC and then use mocks in your test.

With Dependency Injection you will get your object in the constructor by the IoC (which could be, Unity, Simply Injector, Ninject etc.. )

so your method will be like :

```
Public ViewResult GetResult()
{
    var result=_concreteFactory.GetCalculator();
    return View(result);
}
```

And in your test you will use mocking (a good library for that is MoQ ) and setup the return value of `GetCalculator` method .

just Google this and you will find alot of tutorials regrading mocking and dependency injection .

**Edit :**

I'll add that the idea of Unit Test is to test one thing only, and thus we would like to setup the return value of the `GetCalculator` method, because if we would not do it, the test could fail because of the factory - and not because what we wanted to test didn't work .

Comment: What if we reference two classes which are ConcreteFactory1 and ConcreteFactory2. So, based on the suggestion, we have to add two constructor for this controller. We are usiing StructureMap as IOC Contrainer, however, i do not know how to set up different implementation for BaseFactory in such case. Can you help?

Comment: If I understood you right, either `ConcreteFactory1` and `ConcreteFactory2` are two different types totally which then you get both in the same constructor but with two arguments OR they just have different implementation which then you need to get a Interface in your constructor and just send the implementation you want using the IoC container registration . Generally speaking it is always good to use interfaces .